# Display aggregated sum in django html template using Model and Views

Tags: python, html, django

I have created a model.py as below

```
class overallAccountDetail(models.Model):
accountId = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=False, blank=False, 
auto_created=True, null=False,
                                editable=False)
accountName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
countryName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
marketName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
Alarm_Count = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='',blank=True)
TT_Count = models.CharField ( max_length=255 , default='' , blank=True )
```

Views.py

```
def displayAlarmCount(request):
     totalAlarmCount=overallAccountDetail.objects.filter(marketName='Market1', accountName= 'Account1').aggregate(Sum('Alarm_Count')).values()

    ctx = {
    'totalAlarmCount': totalAlarmCount
    }
    return render_to_response('overallaccountdetail_filter.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In HTML template

```
{% block content %}
 <form method="get">
{{ filter.form.as_p }}
<button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
filter.qs.totalAlarmCount<br>
totalAlarmCount
<p><strong>Total Alarm_Count:</strong>{{totalAlarmCount}}</p>
<ul>
{% for overallAccountDetail in filter.qs %}
<li>{{ overallAccountDetail.Alarm_Count }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Now the issue is when i am executing the below query in shell, i am getting the sum of all alarm count of Account1 corresponding to Market 1. But when i am displaying same on html .. it is showing nothing. Please advise what's the problem in my code. The below query shows the exact value in shell that i want to present on the webpage

```
 totalAlarmCount=overallAccountDetail.objects.filter(marketName='Market1', 
 accountName= 'Account1').aggregate(Sum('Alarm_Count')).values()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI your query returns **dict value of decimal like dict_values([Decimal('308617')])**

```
totalAlarmCount=overallAccountDetail.objects.filter(marketName='Market1', 
 accountName= 'Account1').aggregate(Sum('Alarm_Count')).values()
```

So you can change your below like that,

```
sum_count=overallAccountDetail.objects.filter(marketName='Market1', 
     accountName= 'Account1').aggregate(Sum('Alarm_Count'))
totalAlarmCount = sum_count['Alarm_Count__sum']
return render(request, 'overallaccountdetail_filter', {'totalAlarmCount': totalAlarmCount})
```

Comment: Hi Robert, Thanks for the information. I tried using the same, but still the same situation. No output on the webpage

Comment: can you update latest modified code,model,view,template

Comment: No Robert, No error. It is not displaying the output  on webpage, however when i run this on shell it is displaying the output

Comment: I have changed my Views.py and html as below, rest all codes are same

def displayAlarmCount(request):
sum_count = 
  
overallAccountDetail.objects.filter(marketName='MOAI',accountName='Idea').aggregate(Sum('Alarm_Count'))
    totalAlarmCount = sum_count['Alarm_Count__Sum']
    #'WHERE marketName = %s and accountName = %s', account_filter)
    ctx = {
        'totalAlarmCount': totalAlarmCount
    }
    return render_to_response('overallaccountdetail_filter.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


HTML
{% block content %}
{{ totalAlarmCount }}
{% endblock %}

Comment: can you try instated of render_to_response to "return render(request, 'overallaccountdetail_filter', ctx)"

Comment: Its same Robert, No output

Comment: One more thing,.. I am using the below code in url.py 

url(r'^search/$', login, {'template_name':'personal/overallaccountdetail_filter.html'}),

Comment: That's is problem I think

Comment: Ok, how should i do it in url.py then?

Comment: Hello Robert, any advise? on this

Comment: url(r'^marketName_dashboard/$', views.displayAlarmCount, name='marketName_dashboard'),

Comment: do u have githup url can you send me let me check

Comment: Hi Robert- Its working now after updating the above said url

Answer (score 0):

Django promotes the separation of concerns means filtering data should be performed in py file (in your case, same method written above) or in model class. It's still not clear what's filter object in your template from where qs is being fetched? If you can provide that detail then I would be able to help.

Comment: Hi Sachin, I have modified my html template as below:                     {% block content %}

<span id="total">alarm{{  totalAlarmCount }}</span>

{{ totalAlarmCount }}
{% endblock %}  But still its not working. Let me know in case i need to share further info

Comment: Hello Robert-- Problem fixed now. Thanks for the help